# Parse functions and include files

Tags: bison, yacc

I am studying the bison ( yacc ), but I have a doubt, how can I make processing files included in the source (# include) and how can I create functions and to analyze and yacc generate the code for these functions ?

I made a simple test code: https://github.com/bencz/YaccStudy

but, don't have the function system and #include system... I just tried to make, but did it wrong, it gave error at compile time, and when compiled, it did not work ... then deleted the sources that had these changes, and made ​​a new...

Answer (score 1):

bison calls the function `yylex` to read tokens.  If you're defining your own `yylex`, you can make it read from anywhere you like; you just have to turn that source into a sequence of tokens.  If you're using flex, it has a bunch of functions you can use to manipulate the input -- read the manual section on [Multiple Input Buffers](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html)